# Display bootstrap validation icons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know how can I programmatically swap between validation messages once the textbox focus is out.

I have this markup:

```
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;" id="divFirstName" runat="server">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Student First Name" runat="server" id="txtFirstName" clientidmode="Static" value="" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" id="tt2" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" Visible="False"></span>
                                    <span id="inputSuccess2Status" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" Visible="False" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" Visible="False" runat="server" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span id="inputError2Status" class="sr-only" runat="server" Visible="False">(error)</span>
                                    </div>
```

Then I have this script in case there is a value in the textbox:

```
 $(this).attr("aria-describedby", "inputSuccess2Status");
                $("#tt2").attr("visibility", "visible");
                $("#inputSuccess2Status").attr("visibility", "visible");
```

No glyphicon is shown once the script is executed.

Do you see anything wrong? Am I overdoing some things here? What I simply want to do is on focus out of the control, if there is a value show glyphicon-ok otherwise show glyphicon-remove.

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle.net so we can see it live (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you we're looking for?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" style="width: 100%;" id="divFirstName" runat="server">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student First Name" runat="server" id="txtFirstName" clientidmode="Static" value="" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />    
</div>`
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#txtFirstName').change(function(){
    $('.form-control-feedback').remove();
    if($(this).val().length > 0){        
        $('#divFirstName').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" id="tt2" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" Visible="False"></span>');
    }else{
        $('#divFirstName').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" id="tt2" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" Visible="False"></span>');
   }
});
```

**Live Preview**

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9z9vxo5q/)